# Any gotchas in migrating database connectivity to DataSource?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection

Looking at some old application code which uses explicit driver loading as

```
Class.forName(...).newInstance
```

I have been told to change this to use the Java 1.4.2 mechanism to establish a database connection using ContextLookup, and DataSource.

Are there any gotchas I should be aware of?

Comment: Look like just a misconception.

Comment: Is this code to be used in a web container?

Comment: @ Maurice: It's a standalone data migration utility

Comment: I haven't seen a data migration utility that required a pool.  Typically you would open dedicated connections to read, write or update the data in one large batch, so a pool would not add any value.  They don't typically continually run, but are a run once and done sort of deal.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can safely interchange between [`DriverManager#getConnection()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String%29) and the [`DataSource#getConnection()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection%28%29) approaches. You can keep the remnant of the JDBC code untouched as long as it is well-written as per the standard JDBC idiom, that is, acquiring *and* closing resources in the shortest possible scope.

The `DataSource` approach has however the additional benefit that you can easily introduce a connection pool without changing the JDBC code. A connection pool will greatly improve connecting performance.